# Devo utilizar form ou div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

No caso de ser enviado com ajax acredito que ate seja recomendado utilizar a tag form, mas e se eu for so fazer algo com javascript, ou seja somente no lado cliente, por exemplo mudar a cor de fundo da aplicacao, ou gerar algum numero aleatorio, e correto usar form somente pra agrupar um conjuto de labels e inputs?

Comment: Vc pode usar a DIV tb pra agrupar um conjunto de labels e inputs caso não precise do form. `<div id="minhaDiv">labels e inputs aqui</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Tags `form`, intencionam chamadas `HTTP`, não há sentido usá-las para outras finalidades, em requisições `ajax` é interessante usá-las em uma abordagem de [Progressive Enhancement MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Progressive_Enhancement)

ou seja, caso o navegador não suporte `javascript` a requisição será completada da mesma forma, mas isso somente para formulários.

> Tag form [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

*representa uma seção de um documento que contém controles interativos que permitem ao usuário submeter informação a um determinado servidor web.*

> Tag form [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

*O elemento  **PODE** conter um ou mais dos seguintes elementos de formulário:*

```
<input>
<textarea>
<buttom>
<select>
<option>
<optgroup>
<fieldset>
<label>
```

Em nenhuma referência elementos de entrada são obrigatoriamente relacionados a uma tag `form`, somente o contrário, e não há artigos em que isso é considerado boa prática.

Comment: interessante o artigo da mdn, preciso estudar muito mais html e css

Comment: tem algum curso que reensine html e css?

Comment: Gratuitamente o youtube é o caminho, para html, css e jquery recomendo 'curso em video', para javacript, nodejs, e angularjs, pesquise por 'Rodrigo branas'

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou de alguma forma, marque-a como melhor na parte superior esquerda, isso ajuda o site e o demais usuários.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião, `form` deve ser usado sempre que pretende usar tags `input` no código, no mínimo para deixar o código **"claro"** para outros possíveis programadores.

Vejo como se fosse uma história que você escreve sem título, vai funcionar, mas não fica 100% **semântico**.

Exemplo, se você verificar o código fonte da maioria dos sites, vai ver que quando tem um **botão**, dentro de formulário, normalmente está assim:

```
<input type='button'> ou <input type='submit'>
```

mas quando usado fora de um form, na maioria das vezes é usado assim:

```
<button id='x'>Ok</button>
```

ou até mesmo links estilizados como botões

```
<a href='...' class='btn btn-primary'>Ok</a>
```

Comment: form deriva de formulário, digamos que eu queira fazer um sistema de múltipla escolha em SPA, em cada transição vários input rádios são colocados, ou seja se tiver 100 perguntas, terei de abrir 100 tags form sem ao menos usá-los pois serão submetidos em angular, não vejo manutenibilidade nisso. a tag deve ser aberta para toda e qualquer intenção de requisição HTTP e não por conta de componentes externos

Comment: Não entendi direito seu exemplo. Poderia montar um na sua resposta ou passar algum link? Eu imaginei, tanto no caso de usar **div**, quanto **form**, utilizaria apenas um deles e dentro viriam quantos **inputs** fossem necessários.

Comment: Editei para ficar mais claro, mas essa é uma boa discussão acho que vale até uma pergunta